Using Y-DNA and mtDNA from an ancestry file
Ancestry.com DNA results for me and my wife apparently contain Y-chromosome data and mitochondrial data.  How can we use that to find patrilineal and matrilineal matches on sites like FTDNA and GEDMatch?

In general, you can't, at least not currently.  You can upload your autosomal data to FTDNA as autosomal data, and use their FamilyFinder service to match against other aDNA samples.  However, their yDNA and mtDNA offerings are separate tests performed by FTDNA, and can only be compared to other (FTDNA) yDNA or mtDNA samples.  Ancestry's atDNA tests use SNPs (single-nucleotide polymorphisms), whereas the FTDNA lower level yDNA tests (Y-37 and Y-111) use STRs (short tandem repeats), so the data woldn't be comparable in any case.  The Big-Y test uses SNPs, but they don't provide a way to compare it against aDNA uploads.
It's possible that the GEDmatch segment matching tool MIGHT allow you to match segments that show up in your aDNA data file that aren't part of the normal chromosome set.  Even in that case, though, you might only be matching against other Ancestry kits (depending on how much data cleaning other vendors do).
With some effort, you can sometimes glean maternal information from GEDmatch's X-DNA tools, depending on the line of descent.  The chromosome browser on 23AndMe also showed X-DNA segment matches, but since their recent data breach, it seems they've restricted use of the browser.
It's worth noting that mtDNA probably won't help much with identifying maternal lines, unless you're talking about far back in history.  It doesn't mutate nearly as fast as aDNA, so even if you do see a close match, it might only indicate a common ancestor thousands of years ago.
